# Реализация функции atoi

Tags: c, c++

```
int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n;
    n = 0;
    for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    return n;
}
```

Можно ли убрать n и написать `n= 10*(s[i]-'0');`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` содержит накопленное на текущий момент значение. Убрать не получится, если убрать, вы в каждой итерации цикла будете затирать результаты предыдущей итерации.

*Обновление*

```
n *= 10 + (s[i] - '0');
```

— это всё равно что

```
n = n * (10 + (s[i] - '0')));
```

а нужно

```
n = (n * 10) + (s[i] - '0');
```

Comment: n *= 10 + (s[i] - '0');

Comment: @devEugene: Не совсем.

    n *= 10 + (s[i] - '0');

— это всё равно что

    n = n * (10 + (s[i] - '0')));

а нужно

    n = (n * 10) + (s[i] - '0');

Answer (score 5):

Наверное, подразумевалось "убрать i".

```
int atoi(char* s)
{
    int n = 0;
    while( *s >= '0' && *s <= '9' ) {
        n *= 10;
        n += *s++;
        n -= '0';
    }
    return n;
}
```