# программная реализация функции atoi

Tags: c++, преобразование, символы

в теме по ссылке [Реализация функции atoi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/331528/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-atoi/799557#799557)
для меня кое что неясно: зачем от текущей ячейки `s[i]` отнимать символ `'0'`? И можно ли фильтр содержимого сделать как нибудь иначе?

```
n = (n * 10) + (s[i] - '0');
```

Если `n*10` необходимо для формирования разрядности числа (я ведь прав?), то с этим действием (`s[i] - '0'`) не всё ясно. Пожалуйста вкратце объясните.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что **код символа** `'0'` не равен 0.

И чтобы получить численное значение из **символа** `'0'` - вычитаем этот `'0'`. А поскольку символы 0-9 идут подряд, вычитание `'0'` из символа десятичной цифры дает ее значение.